# API Gateway usage with large content payload (video)

Tags: api, content-management-system, gateway, apigee

We have a number of use cases where large file platforms (Youtube, Northplains, and other content repositories) have API's for interacting with their content.   Can anyone share patterns of how API gateway products are being used on those scenarios?  We don't think that the actual upload and download of large payloads should go through our Apigee API gateway but we would like the rest of the interactions across vendor supplied API's to go through our Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you create an API which proxies/mashes up several video content platforms and that your API has a unique search algorithm optimised for specific content retrieval based on specific tags or themes across these multiple targets. Or, you expose a set of new resources on top of these existing APIs which provide extended functionality.

By exposing such APIs, you need to then manage and control the entire developer lifecycle for exposing your API to the public: registration, authentication, access control, throughput control, reporting, mediation and versioning. These are some of the standard features where a platform like Apigee will benefit you, plus there are many more!

Also, Apigee provides the benefit of streaming requests / responses so large payloads (video) are not buffered.

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/endpoint-properties-reference

Hope this helps!

Comment: If [this is you](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ikqureshi), then you should disclose your affiliation in your answers and probably also in your user profile.